# Accidentally upvoting an answer written by a main account while using a sockpuppet?

Tags: discussion, sock-puppets

Let's say I have a main account that I've "retired" from and have created a new account to start afresh. Now say I was looking up an answer to a question and unknowingly stumbled upon an answer written by my main account. Now I could have gone and removed my upvote on that answer, but it was too late by the time I realized. Will both accounts still be suspended even though it was a genuine mistake? Would the mods trust me if I say it was a mistake? I've heard that even one upvote from a sockpuppet can lead to suspension.

Comment: It's probably completely undetectable as long as you don't intentionally do that. (while making a new account to circumvent bans is a violation, it looks like your case is not)

Comment: As a general note: please be aware that “retiring” an old account because that account is question banned can still lead to the new account being removed as that’s seen as evading a system limitation. That is irregardless of voting between the these accounts, accidental or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I won't go into methods - generally sock puppet voting needs an active investigation or a pattern of voting. A one-off vote is likely to be ignored.

There's also usually a broader pattern of abuse with voting fraud.

In practice, I don't really think it's worth the effort of hunting down.

Just be more careful next time.

Comment: *"A one-off vote is likely to be ignored."*???

Comment: @AnnZen Meaning that one vote, on its own, is likely ignored and not considered fraud. So long as it's a one-off event, it's not a big deal.

Comment: Less not considered fraud, more unlikely to be worth the effort